# Dificuldade em fazer RewriteEngine funcionar

Tags: htaccess

Preciso usar esse comando abaixo. No meu servidor funciona bem, mas quando fui instalar em outro essa mesma linha da erro em todo o site.

Preciso disso porque o comando ira vir de forma diferente e quero mascarar a url original do sistema. Tipo:

**www.outrosite.com/aceita/12315544** ou **www.outrosite.com/recusa/12315544**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /transportadora/cotacoesEnviaPropostaAceitarRecusar.php?acao=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Você verificou se o modo rewrite do apache está ativo? Qual é o erro? coloca o print do erro na pergunta para ajudar a responder.

Comment: Experimenta isto http://pastebin.com/BNhp6Ts5

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro verifique se não é uma falha sua no uso do .htaccess, por exemplo, será que o seu servidor usa Apache mesmo ou usa outro como Ngnix.

Verifique também se esta na pasta correta ou se não existe alguma outra pasta.

Não acredito que você tenha esquecido de ligar o modulo, pois se fosse isto teria ocorrido `500 internal error server`.

Tem uma coisa que parece errada no seu rewrite:

Você usou `/transportadora...` quando o correto seria `transportadora...`, ao menos este me parece o mais correto:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ transportadora/cotacoesEnviaPropostaAceitarRecusar.php?acao=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

No entanto o seu `rewrite` esta aceitando qualquer ação e qualquer id, o que é estranho, talvez deve-se tentar isto:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(recusa|aceita)/(\d+)$ transportadora/cotacoesEnviaPropostaAceitarRecusar.php?acao=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

- O `(recusa|aceita)` só aceitará as ações pré-definidas.
- O `\d+` só aceitar numeros.